# Open a terminal tab at a specified directory from command line

Tags: terminal, command-line

I am looking for a script-based solution executed in the command line.

Open a new window of terminal at specified `~/desktop`

```
open -na terminal ~/desktop
```

Open a terminal tab

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'
```

How to open a terminal tab at a particular dir.

Comment: 1. Opening a new tab in Terminal retains the current directory by default! 2. With this knowledge the question answers the question: do some more keystrokes "cd ...." and finally the Enter key ;-)

Comment: Your first command for opening a new window actually opens an entirely new Terminal application instance, which will recreate any windows existing in the current instance!

Answer (score 1):

In MacOS 10.13.2 (but possibly/probably in earlier versions too):

```
    directory=~/Downloads; osascript -e "tell app \"terminal\" to do script \"cd $directory\""
```